# Finding last child of each element

Tags: jquery, css, function, each

I am trying to change the css of the last child of group of elements, if the last child has a specific class.

For instance

```
<div class="box">
<div class="entry"></div>
<div class="entry"></div>
<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="entry"></div>
<div class="entry"></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
<div class="entry"></div>
<div class="entry"></div>
<div class="entry"></div>
<div class="entry"></div>
<div class="divider"></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
<div class="entry"></div>
<div class="entry"></div>
<div class="divider"></div>
<div class="entry"></div>
<div class="entry"></div>
</div>
```

I only want to change the css of the class `"divider"` for the second block of entries because it is the last child. This is what I got so far. Seems like this would work, but alas it is not:

```
$(".entry").each(function() {
  if($(this).is('last-child')) {
    if($(this).hasClass("divider")) {
          $(this).css("border-top-color", "green");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You're looking for a class of 'calendarEntryDivider', but none of your divs have that class. Possible typo?  I'm assuming you wanted to replace 'calendarEntryDivider' with 'divider'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you just need this:

```
$('.divider:last-child').css(...);
```

i.e. change the CSS of every `.divider` that is the `last-child` of its parent.

There's no need for a `.each` because the `.css` function implicitly operates on each matching element.

Comment: @Dave yeah, but my explanation is better ;-)

Comment: whoa, that was easier than my brain was making it out to be. AAARGH BRAIN! Thanks.

Comment: @CareyEstes  also, don't forget that on modern browsers you can do that whole thing in your CSS style sheet without JS.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `:last-child` selector:

```
$('.divider:last-child').css('border-top-color','green')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a colon in your last-child selector, try change it to `:last-child`.

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: It points to the problem in the code, that is why I put it as an answer

Comment: I wrote that before you changed your answer - a missing _semi_colon is rarely a fatal bug in JS.

Comment: I'm sorry for the mistake. It fixed now :)